# Spray routing multiple depth paths

Tags: scala, routes, spray

I have 4 levels of response based on URL. So for:
* GET on `/abc` -> response should be `abc`
* GET on `/abc/def` -> response should be `def`
* GET on `/abc/def/ghi` -> response should be `ghi`
* GET on `/abc/def/ghi/jkl` -> response should be (surprisingly) `jkl`

So my question is how to design that kind of request-response property with Spray.io?

I know that using `pathPrefix` with `path` is possible but that is only for two levels?
With that kind of approach it should look something like:

```
val route = {
  path("/abc") {
    // complete with response 'abc'
  } ~
  path("/abc/def") {
    // complete with response 'def'
  } ~
  path("/abc/def/ghi") {
    // complete with response 'ghi'
  } ~
  path("/abc/def/ghi/jkl") {
    // complete with response 'jkl'
  }
}
```

Is there  any way to "nest paths"? I know this is not working but just an idea like:

```
val route = {
  path("/abc") {
    // complete with response 'abc'
    'sub'path("/def") {
      // complete with response 'def'
      'sub'path("/ghi") {
        // complete with response 'ghi'
        'sub'path("/jkl") {
          // complete with response 'jkl'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Or any other proper way of nesting paths?

Best,
zmeda

Comment: Your first example wouldn't work at all because you need to break out paths as `path("abc" / "def" / "ghi")` etc.

Comment: What do you mean by "I know that using pathPrefix with path is possible but that is only for two levels" ? You can nest `pathPrefix` as deep as you want, just make sure to use `path` on the innermost level.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think the question is about how to do both, complete with something on one level if the path is finished or go one level deeper if there's still more path available.

Try this:

```
val route = {
  pathPrefix("abc") {
    // complete with response 'abc'
    pathEnd { complete("abc") } ~ // don't forget the twiggles
    pathPrefix("def") {
      pathEnd { complete("def") } ~
      pathPrefix("ghi") {
        pathEnd { complete("ghi") } ~
        path("jkl") { // path already includes pathEnd, path(x) = pathPrefix(x ~ PathEnd)
          complete("jkl")
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Btw. this doesn't match "/abc/" etc., i.e. a path with a trailing slash. If you want to match trailing slashes mandatorily or optionally use `pathSingleSlash` or `pathEndOrSingleSlash` instead of `pathEnd`.